# Why can't I assign the value of property in this case?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Here's my code:

```js
let obj = {};

obj.__proto__ = "some value";
console.log(obj.__proto__ == Object.prototype);
```

Does it happen because of the `set __proto__`, which regulates the assignment process and allows only objects or `null` be the value of `__proto__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [`__proto__` setter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-object.prototype.__proto__) is required to do, on step 2:

> If Type(proto) is neither Object nor Null, return undefined.

in which case it does nothing, and the previous prototype remains unchanged.

Also note that `__proto__` is deprecated, and should be avoided in favor of `setPrototypeOf` (and `getPrototypeOf`), which makes the error explicit:

```js
let obj = {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, "some value");
```